# Angular 4 Reset Button Resets DropDown Default Value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dropdown

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Type--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
                {{ powerPlantType }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Status--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
                {{ powerPlantStatus }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.reset()">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

The layout for which looks like this:

[image]

When I click the Reset button, the default values for the drop down disappears - as shown in the figure below.

[image]

How do I make sure that the default value is retained even after hitting the Reset button?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have an additional value in the list of elements with `id = -1`

```
types:any[]=[
                {id:-1,Name:'Select One'},
                {id:1,Name:'abc'},
                {id:2,Name:'abdfsdgsc'}
    ];
```

HTML will look as

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement.id">
     <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.id"> {{type.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

On Reset

```
reset(){
   this.selectedElement = {id:-1,Name:'Select One'};
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AmCklbYxL2TDMT4iGQAY?p=preview)**

Comment: I will give this a try! What is the benefit of having an additional value in the list?

Comment: you will be able to reset to the default one

Comment: Why can't I do without the id element?

Comment: I'm doing this in my reset function this.model.powerPlantType = ''; Isn't this enough?

Comment: @sparkr yes it is enough. do you need any more help?

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove the form reference from f.reset(), change to reset(). Where reset() is the component class method:

   ```
   reset(){
       this.model.powerPlantType = '';
       this.model.powerPlantStatus = '';
       // and other input resettings too
     }
   ```

   And then change

   ```
   <button type="button" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
   ```

   [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx3uwx)

2. Change the button type from "button" to "reset":

   ```
   <button type="reset>Reset</button>
   ```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhthhb)